Clear and automatic DAG visualization
I am trying to draw a DAG (directed acyclic graph) starting from a dataframe with  212 attributes.
I am able to draw it using graphviz
import graphviz

G = graphviz.Digraph()

for col in graph_df.columns:
    for row in graph_df.index:
        if graph_df.loc[row, col] == 1:
            G.edge(col, row)

G.render('graph', format='pdf', cleanup=True)

But the final pdf looks like this

If I zoom I can read everything, but I would like to stretch vertically the final DAG to have it tidier. Can you help me please?

10,10 it is too small, but even if I put 1000,9000 the format remains like the one I posted, it is very flat

You can use ratio and size, if you need vertically long graph display:
G = graphviz.Digraph(graph_attr={'rankdir': 'TB', 'ratio': 'fill', 'size': '50,200'})

Code:
import pandas as pd
import graphviz


def get_plot(graph_df):
    G = graphviz.Digraph(graph_attr={'rankdir': 'TB', 'ratio': 'fill', 'size': '10,30'})
    for i, col in enumerate(graph_df.columns):
        for j, row in enumerate(graph_df.index):
            if i != j and graph_df.loc[row, col] == 1:  # Ensure not connecting a node to itself
                G.edge(col, row)

    G.render('graph', format='pdf', cleanup=True)


V = 26
nodes = [chr(ord('A') + i) for i in range(V)]
edges = {name: [1 if i != j else 0 for j in range(V)] for i, name in enumerate(nodes)}
df = pd.DataFrame(edges, index=nodes)
get_plot(df)


Actual Size


You can change the size to get what's expected.



node_attr() and graph_attr() has everything that you need to customize your view:

import pandas as pd
import graphviz


def get_plot(graph_df):
    G = graphviz.Digraph(
        graph_attr={
            'rankdir': 'TB',
            'ratio': 'fill',
            'size': '100,200',
            'nodesep': '1.0',
            'ranksep': '1.5'
        },
        node_attr={
            'fixedsize': 'true',
            'width': '10.0',
            'height': '10.0',
            'fontsize': '300'
        }
    )
    for i, col in enumerate(graph_df.columns):
        for j, row in enumerate(graph_df.index):
            if i != j and graph_df.loc[row, col] == 1:
                G.edge(col, row)

    G.render('graph', format='pdf', cleanup=True)


V = 26
nodes = [chr(ord('A') + i) for i in range(V)]
edges = {name: [1 if i != j else 0 for j in range(V)] for i, name in enumerate(nodes)}
df = pd.DataFrame(edges, index=nodes)
get_plot(df)


10% view (of the actual size)


Hi, thanks for the suggestion but even if the general graph is wider, now I am not able to see anymore node's names, neither if I zoom.

I am able to see the node's names by zooming only if I download the pdf and open it with a proper PDF visualizer (not preview like Jupyter)

@Zackbord Exactly. Also, see my update. node_attr and graph_attr has several options such as width and height of the nodes and fontsize, etc.

Without seeing the input, only guesses:

try other Graphviz engines - neato, twopi, circo, fdp
increase ranksep (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/ranksep/)
increase nodesep (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nodesep/)
try setting TBbalance (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/TBbalance/)
look at unflatten (https://graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf)

